# If $A⊗_{F}E≅B⊗_{F}E$, then $A≅B$??

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let A,B be finitely generated modules over field F and E be a field extension of F.

The problem is :

If $A⊗_{F}E≅B⊗_{F}E$ as E-module,

then prove $A≅B$ as F-module.

I tried to prove it using $Hom(A,B)⊗C≅Hom(A⊗C,B⊗C)$
and $Hom(A⊗B,C)≅Hom(A,Hom(B,C))$

Comment: f.g. over a field are also called finite dimensional vector spaces. Those have bases, so are free

Comment: Max has given the best answer for your particular situation, but there is a general principle at work here, namely that of faithful flatness.